# how to make section title sit lower in the section

Tags: ios, sections

i have spaced out the sections accordingly but the titles i have are centered[image]

but i would like to have it like this 
[image]

its probably a real simple fix but i dont seem to be able to find it i tried playing with header footer view methods but no go, also the color of it i would like and the outline frame around the section is also what i would like thank you
[image]

Comment: set tableView section title.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You need to implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`, *not* `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`. You can thus return the *entire view*, colored as you like, and with the label positioned inside it as you like. You must also implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` because otherwise the table may try to resize your view in a way you don't want.

An easy way to design the view is to make a view *.xib* file and design it there. You'll probably want to use a UIView subclass so you can access the label inside it later through an outlet. In `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`, load the nib, pull out the view, configure the label, and return the view.